# Лаги при прорисовке изображения в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.time import Clock


def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 900))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        screen.fill((230, 230, 230))

        img = pygame.image.load('images/img.jpg')
        screen.blit(img, (0,0))

        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
        pygame.display.update() 

run()
```

При прорисовке изображений в pygame всё дико лагает. При прорисовке изображения с разрешением 1200x800, fps = 5.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вынести загрузку картинки из цикла, т.к. нет смысла 60 раз в секунду ее загружать:

```
import pygame


def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 900))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    img = pygame.image.load('images/img.jpg')

    while True:
        screen.fill((230, 230, 230))
        screen.blit(img, (0, 0))

        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
        pygame.display.update() 

run()
```